# Is there a way to update a eav custom attribute?

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes

My eav is:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'bid_target',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Bid Target',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'sort_order' => 0,
            'group' => 'Informazioni Bid',
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

I get it with:

```
        $bid_prodotto = $prodotto->getResource()->getAttribute("bid_target")->getFrontend()->getValue($prodotto);
```

but i'm not able to update this value. Some tips? Thanks :)

Comment: From where you want to update, write more detail with specific M2 version.

Comment: From my custom Observer, when proceed-checkout trigger start

Comment: Example: $prodotto->updateAttribute("bid_target", $old + 1);

Answer (score 1):

The EAV setup class `vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php` has an `updateAttribute` function :

```
/**
 * Update Attribute data and Attribute additional data
 *
 * @param int|string $entityTypeId
 * @param int|string $id
 * @param string|array $field
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param int $sortOrder
 * @return $this
 */
public function updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $id, $field, $value = null, $sortOrder = null)
{
    $this->_updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $id, $field, $value, $sortOrder);
    $this->_updateAttributeAdditionalData($entityTypeId, $id, $field, $value);
    return $this;
}
```

Use it in your module `UpgradeData.php` class.

Comment: i mean a dynamic update, when an event is captured and not an static and fixed upgrade of an attribute. Thanks

Comment: @Paolovox please update your question with this information :)